# Calculating mean from values in columns specified on the first line using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a huge file (hundreds of lines, ca. 4,000 columns) structured like this

```
locus   1   1   1   2   2   3   3   3
exon    1   2   3   1   2   1   2   3
data1   17.07   7.11    10.58   10.21   19.34   14.69   3.32    21.07
data2   21.42   11.46   7.88    9.89    27.24   12.40   0.58    19.82
```

and I need to calculate mean from all values (on each data line separately) with the same locus number (i.e., the same number in the first line), i.e.

> data1: mean from first three values (three columns with locus '1':
>   17.07, 7.11, 10.58), next two values (10.21, 19.34) and next three values (14.69, 3.32, 21.07)

I would like to have output like this

```
data1   mean1   mean2   mean3
data1   mean1   mean2   mean3
```

I was thinking about using bash and awk...
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: bash is for manipulating files and processes, not for text processing - you just need awk for that. [edit] your question to show the exact output you want given that input and exactly how you would want to call a tool that could do that. Also include what you have tried so far, even if it's just pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) version 1.1.0 or newer (I used last version - 1.1.1):

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(wc -l < "$1")

datamash -W transpose < "$1" |
datamash -H groupby 1 mean 3-"$lines" |
datamash transpose
```

**Usage:** `mean_value.sh input.txt | column -t` (`column -t` needed for pretty view, it is not necessary)

**Output:**

```
GroupBy(locus)  1                2       3
mean(data1)     11.586666666667  14.775  13.026666666667
mean(data2)     13.586666666667  18.565  10.933333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

if it was me, i would use `R`, not `awk`:

```
library(data.table)
x = fread('data.txt')

#> x
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7   V8    V9
#1: locus  1.00  1.00  1.00  2.00  2.00  3.00 3.00  3.00
#2:  exon  1.00  2.00  3.00  1.00  2.00  1.00 2.00  3.00
#3: data1 17.07  7.11 10.58 10.21 19.34 14.69 3.32 21.07
#4: data2 21.42 11.46  7.88  9.89 27.24 12.40 0.58 19.82

# save first column of names for later
cnames = x$V1

# remove first column
x[,V1:=NULL]

# matrix transpose: makes rows into columns
x = t(x)

# convert back from matrix to data.table
x = data.table(x,keep.rownames=F)

# set the column names
colnames(x) = cnames

#> x
#   locus exon data1 data2
#1:     1    1 17.07 21.42
#...

# ditch useless column
x[,exon:=NULL]

#> x
#   locus data1 data2
#1:     1 17.07 21.42

# apply mean() function to each column, grouped by locus
x[,lapply(.SD,mean),locus]

#   locus    data1    data2
#1:     1 11.58667 13.58667
#2:     2 14.77500 18.56500
#3:     3 13.02667 10.93333
```

for convenience, here's the whole thing again without comments:

```
library(data.table)
x = fread('data.txt')
cnames = x$V1
x[,V1:=NULL]
x = t(x)
x = data.table(x,keep.rownames=F)
colnames(x) = cnames
x[,exon:=NULL]
x[,lapply(.SD,mean),locus]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '   NR==1{for(i=2;i<NF+1;i++) multi[i]=$i} 
        NR>2{
            for(i in multi)
            {   
                data[multi[i]] = 0 
                count[multi[i]] = 0 
            }   
            for(i=2;i<NF+1;i++) 
            {    
                data[multi[i]] += $i    
                count[multi[i]] += 1
            }; 

            printf "%s ",$1; 
            for(i in data) 
                printf "%s ", data[i]/count[i]; 
            print ""  
        }' <file_name>
```

Replace `<file_name>` with your data file

Comment: Thanks for the nice code, however, it works correctly only for the first data line, the values on the second line are incorrect. Correct values are data1 11.587 14.775 13.027
data2 13.587 18.565 10.933
But with the code above it is data1 11.5867 14.775 13.0267
data2 12.5867 16.67 11.98

Comment: yeah I just noticed.. seems like the `data` and `count` were not set to zero per line. the code was edited accordingly